# PHP, Editing a post in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making an editing post feature for my site, but I'm stuck at this. This is my code:

```
$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["story"]);
mysql_select_db("xxxxxx", $con);

$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO tool WHERE id=$post (title, details, author) 
VALUES
('$_POST[title]','$_POST[details]','$_SESSION[Username]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "The story<b> " . $_POST[title] . " </b>has been edited.";

mysql_close($con)
```

I know the error has something to do with `INSERT IGNORE INTO tool WHERE id=$post`. I obviously don't want to change every post in the DB to the same thing, so I need it to find the post ID, which is `$post`, and then change the info for just that specific DB item.

Comment: I smell SQL injection! And consider `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and then fix the notices you get.

Comment: holy SQL injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Lets not forget our old friend XSS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Safely_validating_untrusted_HTML_input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides SQL injection, as @ThiefMaster and @djdy opposed (and that is iminent) it is much better to use UPDATE query for updating (editing) an existing entry (rather then INSERT IGNORE where INSERT should only be used for inserting of new entries).

Your query then should be:

```
$sql="
    UPDATE `tool` SET 
        `title` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', 
        `details` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details'])."', 
        `author` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Username'])."' 
    WHERE `id` = $post;";
```

You have to escape the MySQL reserved words like `id`, etc, using backquotes. Also using a `mysql_real_escape_string()` on every value passed into a query is a very good habit.

Comment: got confused by ORA which i'm working with right now... Sorry then... :-)

But if `id` become a reserved word in near future, his query won't fail if it escapes it today :-)

Answer (score 9):

INSERT is for new records, you need to use UPDATE if you want to change a record.

Answer (score 1):

Woah, you have several major errors:

```
$post = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["story"]); // why are you mixing $_POST and $_GET?
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]); // always escape user-generated input that's being put into a SQL query statement
$detai = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["details"]);
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["Username"]);

$sql = "UPDATE `tool` SET `title` = '$title', `details` = '$details', `author` = '$author' WHERE `id` = '$post'"; // correct syntax for an UPDATE query
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

you can try REPLACE instead of INSERT syntax is :

```
REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
```

and refer this site http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

You must using error_reporting [functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and get error description. So you can detect where you wrong.

Also to edit record you must using something like

```
update posts set title = 'new title', content = 'new content' where post_id = <your_post_id>
```

So you must implement functionality that detect (provide) unique post id.